# Why am I having an invalid syntax in my python code?

Tags: python, syntax

I have a invalid syntax on this line and I can't find why. I am running this python scrypt in a docker container on my ubuntu terminal.

```
File "faceit_live.py", line 288
    >>>>>>> HEAD:faceit_live.py
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the section of the code :

```
                if (webcam):
                    time.sleep(1/30.0)
                    # firefox needs RGB 
<<<<<<< HEAD:faceit_live.py
                    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
                    # chrome and skype UYUV - not working at the
=======
                    # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
                    # chrome and skype UYUV - not working at the moment
>>>>>>> 5f793ec35b6dc9d88cd20faa6bd6ed4acf65b10c:faceit_live.py
                    # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

                    camera.schedule_frame(image)
                    #print("writing to stream")

                else:
                    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
                    #print("writing to screen")

                # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    video_capture.release()
                    break

            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit()
```

Comment: This isn't a proper source file; something went wrong with your version control, and you have to merge the changes manually before it will work again.

Comment: why do you put ` >>>>>>> HEAD:faceit_live.py` in code ? It is not Python's code.

Comment: Thx, problem solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines and the problem is solved:

`<<<<<<< HEAD:faceit_live.py`

`=======`

`>>>>>>> 5f793ec35b6dc9d88cd20faa6bd6ed4acf65b10c:faceit_live.py`

This probably occurred from a git merge conflict.